# Is the following a reflection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Let $A^2=A$ so that $A$ is a projection, $B^2=I$, and $B=2A-I$. Is it true that $B$ represents a reflection?

Comment: try it in $n=2.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in general.

For even $n$ and $A=0$, we get $B=-I_n$ which has determinant $1$ and therefore isn't a reflection.

Comment: At least, that's what distinguishes reflections for me: orthogonal transformations with determinant $-1$. Let me know if you're thinking of something else.

Comment: In the case that $A \neq 0$ is it true that $B$ is a reflection matrix?

Comment: @mtiano No. If $ A=I$ then $B=I$ is not a reflection.